# Не получается включить режим разработчика android

Tags: android

Не получается включить режим разработчика на телефоне Fly IQ 442. Делаю  все как обычно тапаю на "номер сборки" 7 раз, пробовал больше раз, пробовал по другим пунктам тапать, с разной скоростью - но ничего. Впервые с таким сталкиваюсь, может есть какие то альтернативные способы. Или я что то неправильно делаю, просто во всех туториалах  одно и тоже: " 7 раз по номеру сборки "

p.s. но при этом есть пункт в меню "настройки" - "параметры разработчика" - значит ли это, что режим разработчика включен,  т.к. мое приложение все равно не запускается, пишет  "В приложении произошла ошибка" ?

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my.project"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

//facebook sdk
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'

//my dependencies
compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
```

}

Comment: а как Вы пытаетесь установить приложение?

Comment: @KoVadim в данном случае закинув его на карту памяти телефона. у меня это обычно работает!

Comment: http://www.androidpit.ru/android-dlya-novichkov-kak-ustanovit-storonnee-prilozhenie

Comment: пункт меню "Отладка через USB" включен?

Comment: @KoVadim я его в папку "загрузки" и кладу, оттуда же и пытаюсь установить!

Comment: @Александр включил, это должно помочь?  порядок действий по установке приложения нужно поменять или делать все как делал?

Comment: все равно, куда Вы его "кладете". Должна быть отмечена галочка "установка с сторонних источников" (она может по разному называться).

Comment: Я просто не совсем понимаю, что подразумевается под "приложение не устанавливается"

Comment: @KoVadim опция "установка с сторонних источников"  была включена при первой установке

Comment: Как устанавливается приложение? Через `apk` файл ? Если приложение устанавливается через `IDE` (`AndroidStudio` или прочее), то в логах можно посмотреть ошибки.

Comment: @Александр пардон, за неправильную формулировку, пишет "В приложении произошла ошибка" . На других  устройствах  телефоне, планшете все работает - ок!

Comment: Судя по обновлению вопроса - вполне возможно, что приложени скомпилировано для другого типа телефона или apk не совсем apk (битый).

Comment: Ну тут как бы не скажешь однозначно, в чем ошибка, логи нужно смотреть

Comment: @Александр версия прошивки на устройстве 4.0.4 в файле сборки тоже вроде все норм. И все таки  - режим разработчика не понятно включен или нет!

Comment: @KoVadim что подразумевается для другого типа телефона?

Comment: @KirillStoianov, в меню разработчика выбрать "отладка через usb", потом появится окошко с текстом, согласны ли вы и все такое и нажать ОК.

Comment: андроид приложение может содержать нативный код. В этом случае он должен быть для каждой поддерживаемой платформы. Если для какой то его нет,  работать не будет.

Comment: Попалась ошибка в логах. Проблема в xml. Если кратко  - пишет это 
inary XML file line #24: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1

Comment: создам новый вопрос...

Comment: Иногда бывает такой косяк, если package содержит слово example, попробуйте поменять в манифесте package, и посмотреть, что из этого выйдет